# CSS Transform hover bug in Webkit when using perspective, rotateX, rotateY and scale

Tags: css, webkit, transform, transition

I have the following fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cYwkz/

I'm using the following CSS:

```
article {
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 2% 32px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}
article:hover {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(5deg) scale(1.025);
  -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(5deg) scale(1.025);
  -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(5deg) scale(1.025);
  -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(5deg) scale(1.025);
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(5deg) scale(1.025);
}
```

When I hover the left-bottom part of the articles, the hover and transforms work as correctly. However when I hover over the right-top part, the transform flickers or sometimes doesn't start at all. 
I don't have these problems in Firefox.

System: Mac OSX 10.9.1
Works in: Firefox 26, Firefox Aurora 28, IE10
Fails in: Chrome 32, Safari 7.0.1, Opera Next 19

Hope you guys can help! Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this happens because transforms in Webkit are still prefixed, that is not stable. I can confirm that the bug is present even in Chrome 34 (latest Canary to the date, OS X).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that in webkit the plane situated at z=0 gets the hover events (so to speak).

Since your rotation makes the elements (specially the right top part) go away (or inside the screen), they get under the zplane and no longer trigger the hover.

You can solve that moving them towards z positive:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(5deg) 
                   translateZ(10px) scale(1.025);
```

To avoid the Z movement in the hover state, set the same Z in the base state.

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
                   translateZ(10px) scale(1);
```

It's always a good idea, when using transitions, to set the base transform in the same way that the transformed state. That's why I set the 0deg rotations.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/cYwkz/3/)

Comment: You can set any value that you like, as long as it high enough to move all the div above the z plane. A more *mathematic* way would be to rotate around the top right corner (so the net movement would be to raise) but then I don't know how to set the base state.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction but it solved my problem :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this code below

```
<style>    
.outer div {
        float: left;
        -webkit-perspective: 200px;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .outer a {
        -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        background:#0F6;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:block;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    }
    .outer div:hover a {
        -webkit-transform: none;
    }
</style>

    <div class="outer">
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This solution works for me in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/jaxweb/7qtLD/7/